# WKWebView not playing video in landscape mode only in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, wkwebview

Rotating the device does not rotate the currently playing video. It works great in iOS 8 and 9.

Can't find any changes in WebKit that could cause this behaviour. I'm just instantiating a WKWebView with regular configurations.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm seeing the same issue.

Comment: No luck 
Fixed it defining the orientation of the app as landscape when I know the video is playing. Then, when it ends, force the app to be displayed in portrait mode again.
A pretty hacky solution, would love a more appropriate one.

Comment: @ivopintodasilva care to share how did you force rotate back to portrait after setting it on landscape? I can't get seem to force mine back to portrait.

Comment: @Teffi Basically you can put a 'rotationEnabled' boolean in your AppDelegate and implement the 'supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor' method.
When 'rotationEnabled' is active, you return '.allButUpsideDown' on that method. Else return '.portrait'.

Comment: A very hacky solution but it's the one that suited me best at the time 

Comment: @ivopintodasilva I actually tried that but it won't go back to portrait once it escaped from fullscreen landscape mode. https://gist.github.com/teffi/ad31e948971e1e7fa1a77e4ddbd2b3f7